# HTML Canvas not accepting bold font on mobile

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a simple HTML5 canvas on the page

```
<canvas class="wapf-canvas"></canvas>
```

Whenever I set the font to bold, it works on desktop but not on mobile:

```
var ctx = document.querySelector('.wapf-canvas').getContext('2d')
ctx.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
```

`console.log(ctx.font)` shows `12px sans-serif`, so it ommited the bold font-weight for some reason. Here is the output from Safari mobile:

[image]

Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can  see for ourselves

Comment: Try running `document.fonts.check( 'bold 10px sans-serif' )` instead and see what the outcome is. _It might just not exists_ - you are looking on a different device after all.

Comment: Just tried on browserstack and indeed, the font getter seems buggy, but that's also true for the desktop version... However, the drawn result is just fine, even on the iphone.